# Landau's Problem - Poisson bracks of a spherical symmetry function and angular momuntum in z axis

Tags: homework-and-exercises, symmetry, hamiltonian-formalism, poisson-brackets

In landau's Mechanics, there's a problem:

[image: Problem]

I think, if the function has the property spherical symmetry, or:
$\phi(r,p)=\phi(-r,-p)$

The form suggested by Landau follows this property, but I can't reason that all function having this property depend only on $r^2$, $p^2$ and $r\cdot p$. Is there a formal proof for this (that any spherical symmetry function must  <del>be a combination of</del>  (Edit: not necessary a combination) depends only on $r^2$, $p^2$ and $r\cdot p$) ?

---

Update 1:

I realized that a spherical symmetry function must depend only on some sort of scalar variable, otherwise the function would depend on the direction of variable and thus is not spherical symmetry. But isn't $r\cdot p$ somehow depends on the relative direction of both vectors?

---

Update 2:

A little visualization of pppqqq's idea. I decompose the transformation into four single-axis rotation, since it is much eaiser to understand and easy to write out their matrix representation (See: [Wikipedia - Rotation Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) ). The four rotation are clearly orthogonal transformations and the composition of them is thus orthogonal. Here also explains that the term $r\cdot p$ arise from that $r$ is not always perpendicular to $p$.

- Step 1 (ignore the momentum $p$ first):

[image: step 1]

- Step 2:

[image: step 2]

- Step 3 (Now is the momentum. Wherever $p$ lies, we can do the same thing as we have done in step 1.):

[image: step3]

- Finally:

[image: finally]

Comment: There are several vague questions here. It's much better to pose a singe specific question. Make multiple posts for multiple questions.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I have reduced it to one question. @DanielSank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "the function is spherically simmetrical" means that, if $G$ is an orthogonal transformation (that sends spheres into themselves), then $$f(G\mathbf r, G\mathbf p,t)=f(\mathbf r , \mathbf p, t).$$
If you know $\mathbf r^2$, $\mathbf p^2$, $\mathbf r \cdot \mathbf p$ you can calculate $f$ by taking an orthogonal transformation which maps $\mathbf r$ into the $z$ axis and $\mathbf p$ into the $x-z$ plane, so it's clear that such a function depends on $\mathbf r $ and $\mathbf p$ only via those combinations.

---

Explicitly: $$f(x,y,z,p_x,p_y,p_z)=f(0,0,r,p\sin \theta,0,p\cos \theta),$$
where $$\cos \theta =\dfrac{\mathbf p\cdot \mathbf r}{pr}.$$

Comment: Your reasoning is quite cool. May I ask if it is always possible to found a transformation which is orthogonal and maps r into the z axis and p into the x−z plane. Is there a example of this sort?

Comment: I guess you are looking for the explicit form of the rotation. I'm sorry but I don't have time right now to write a formal proof. However the idea is very simple: WLOG take $\mathbf r$ as the $z$ axis. If $\theta$ is the longitude of $\mathbf p$ in spherical coordinates, the next step is a simple rotation about the $z$ axis of an angle $-\theta$.

Comment: Many thanks. I also updated my visualization of your thought.

Comment: You are welcome. As to your update #1, ofcourse $\mathbf r \cdot \mathbf p$ depends on the relative direction of $\mathbf r$ and $\mathbf p$; if you want, it *defines* the direction of $\mathbf r$ with respect to $\mathbf p$. Maybe "spherical symmetric" isn't a very good way to say that a function is invariant under rotations of the coordinate axis (in my translation its replaced by the word "scalar", if I remember well).